# How to blink specific node in d3js collapsible tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a collapsible tree in d3js. I have a select2 to select one of leaf nodes. When leaf node is selected the node should blink(forever). I have following code but it blinks only once.

```
  $("#search").on("select2:select", function (e) {
            var theNode = d3.selectAll(".node")
                    .filter(function (d) {
                        return d.name == e.params.data.text
                    });
            console.log(theNode);
            setInterval(blink(theNode),3000);

        });

        function blink(Node) {
            Node.style("opacity", "0")
                    .transition()
                    .duration(1000)
                    .style("opacity", 1.0)
        }
```

Comment: `setInterval(function (){ blink(theNode); },3000)`

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm!

Comment: How can I stop it blinking?

Comment: Please, don't make questions in the comments, post it as a new question. But the answer is `clearInterval`.